# Leaving due to commute and pay a good reason to leave?

Tags: career-development, job-change

I am dissatisfied for the following reasons at work:

- The commute is taking me 1 hour and 15 minutes one way. It is starting to wear me out since I am travelling 2 hours and 30 minutes each day. It is hard for me to get in on time. We recently moved offices, my boss did not take this into account. It is now getting to the point where it is starting to become an issue for him, since he is pointing it out.
- The pay does not reflect the stress I am under, if a project is going badly, I am questioned why and generally given a hard time. It does not matter if I have performed consistently well prior to that one project. I only seem to be as good as the last project I have delivered.

I am also often paid late to the point that I am now having to remind my boss to pay my salary.

The only reason why I am staying is because I feel comfortable here, where I am feeling a bit daunted by the prospect of moving jobs and questioning if things will improve with new management - I have over a year project management experience now.

Are these good reasons to consider leaving?

Answer (score 6):

**Yes, these are good reasons to consider leaving your current employment.**

A long commute is damaging to your physical and mental health for a variety of reasons [(Hilbrecht, Smale & Mock, 2014)](http://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/16078055.2014.903723) [(Nie & Sousa-Poza, 2016)](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S1043951X16300189) [(Sandow, Westerlund & Lindgren, 2014)](http://m.epn.sagepub.com/content/46/6/1496.short). Other studies demonstrated a mean commute of less than 30 minutes one-way in an urban USA population, and on this scale health effects were still notable.

As well, consistently late payment of income is a major red flag that the employer is being financially mismanaged (either they have money but can't organise, or don't have much money and are stalling). As income is a major factor in employment, this alone is also enough to justify seeking a new workplace.

Comment: The late payment itself is enough in my book. The rest can be negotiated, depending on the situation. But not the late payment. A firm that pays late cannot expect people to stay loyal.

Comment: A company's top priority must be on-time payroll. If a company cannot pay employees, it cannot function.

Comment: It usually indicates problem with financial management, and you just don't want to be on the receiving end of bad financial management.

Answer (score 2):

> Are these good reasons to consider leaving?

Is there a better job available? If yes, then that is all the reason you need to change jobs. It does not matter why it's better. Whether it pays more, has more benefits, is closer to your home or has strawberries for lunch every day. If it's available and it's better than your current one, go for it.

Since I have read many of your questions here and over at PM, I'd say go for it *now*. The other job is bound to be better, you don't need a crystal ball for that.

Answer (score 0):

In short: yes, absolutely.

If your commute is so long that it's hard to get to work on time, then it absolutely makes sense to either switch jobs,  or move. You might even ask for relocation assistance, since you're moving only because the office moved. But you never signed up for this commute distance, so of course you are free to decide you don't want to do it.

Likewise, an insufficient salary is probably the number one reason why people leave their jobs. Again, there is an alternative to leaving, which is to ask for a raise.

Since looking for a new job can be a lot of work, it's worth your while to see if moving closer and getting a hike in pay are possibilities. But if they're not: dust off the resume and find a better situation.

Answer (score 0):

Are you happy with current arrangement? Do you see yourself working in there for next X years?

This is not a question that needs objective answer - what you feel matters.

Personally, I wouldn't want to commute over 1h per day, unless the opportunity (and pay) was excellent.